# Gradle DSL method not found error for custom task?

Tags: android, gradle

I have two custom gradle tasks in my android application. The app's build.gradle file looks like following:

```
task A(type: Exec) {
    ... do something ...
}

task B(type: Exec, dependsOn: ['A']) {
    ... do something ...
}
```

I want these two tasks to be executed before android build starts. So I put the following line in my build.gradle file:

```
preBuild.dependsOn(B)
```

When I do a gradle sync, I get the following error message:

```
 Error:Gradle DSL method not found: 'B()'
```

What is the problem? What steps should I take to resolve this?

Comment: Could you please provide a full build script, because it's not enought info here to say exacrly reason of the exception